# how to solve error "Undefined property: Session::$session"?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can I get any suggestion to solve this issue? 
My controller page is (session.php)

```
class Session extends CI_Controller    {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("session_model");
        $language = $this->session->userdata('lang');
        $this->lang->load('session', $language);
        $this->load->helper('ff_helper');
    }

    public function index() {   
        $query=$this->db->query('select * from school_sessions');
        $rows=$query->result();
        $data=array( 'result'=>$rows);
        $this->data["subview"] = "session/index";
        $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
    }

}
```

i have created model page & view page but i want to display last login history of any user from my database.

In database, login session is updated but once i am going to display then not showing

```
error is showing
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Session::$session

Filename: controllers/session.php

Line Number: 8
```

Comment: may be Class name *Session* is problem

Comment: `Filename: controllers/Session.php`

Comment: I have changed but same problem..A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Session::$session

Filename: controllers/Session.php

Comment: in my code...line no:8 is .....$language = $this->session->userdata('lang');
line no:9 is .....  $this->lang->load('session', $language);